# Assigning dbo.owner permissions to a SPN in terraform

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, terraform

I am trying to app and SPN (that the pipeline runs on) as dbo.owner on a sql database that terraform provisions.

I have created the MSI (Managed Service Identity) on the SQL Server by :

```
 identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
```

In the SQL block.

So I need terraform to use this MSI to assign a very simple t-sql statement like :

```
ALTER ROLE [dbo.owner] etc
```

I have also found this 3rd party terraform resource [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/betr-io/mssql/latest/docs/resources/user)

I am just wandering if anyone has put all this together..
Thx